# Is sending a hashed password over the wire a security hole?

Tags: security, hash, authentication, passwords

I've come across a system that is in use by a company that we are considering partnering with on a medium-sized (for us, not them) project.

They have a web service that we will need to integrate with.

My current understanding of proper username/password management is that the username may be stored as plaintext in the database. Every user should have a unique pseudo-random salt, which may also be stored in plaintext. The text of their password must be concatenated with the salt and then this combined string may be hashed and stored in the database in an nvarchar field. So long as passwords are submitted to the website (or web service) over **SSL**, everything should be just lovely.

Feel free to rip into my understanding as summarized above if I'm wrong.

Anyway, back to the subject at hand. The WebService run by this potential partner doesn't accept username and password, which I had anticipated. Instead, it accepts two string fields named 'Username' and 'PasswordHash'. The 'PasswordHash' value that I have been given does indeed look like a hash, and not just a value for a mis-named password field.

This is raising a red flag for me. I'm not sure why, but I feel uncomfortable sending a hashed password over the wire for some reason. Off the top of my head I can't think of a reason why this would be a bad thing... Technically, the hash is available on the database anyway. But it's making me nervous, and I'm not sure if there's a reason for this or if I'm just being paranoid.

**EDIT**

I was confused by some of the comments below until I re-read my post.

In the original, I had the phrase "So long as passwords are submitted to the website (or web service) over **plaintext**, everything should be just lovely."

I swear that as I thought that I was thinking the term 'SSL'. For some reason I typed the word 'plaintext' instead. Wow.

Worst. Typo. Ever.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no value on using the hashed password to send it to the service, given you'd still need a separate mechanism to secure the communication i.e. SSL

If the system accepts the hashed password, for all intends and purposes the hashed password **is** the password. If an attackers gets the hashed password, (s)he has access to the account without needing to figure out the original password.

One important issue with all the above, is that if the db is compromised & an attacker gets the hashed passwords, that means instant access to all the accounts through the said WebService, since as far as the WebService cares those are already the passwords.

I really suggest you take it to them & talk about it. It might be one of those things that some dev did & haven't gained the attention/priority to straight it out.

Comment: Thanks for that Freddy. I think I will - still, it's good to know it isn't as bad as I'd originally feared.

Comment: Freddy is right: the hashed password IS the password then. Unless the 'hash' was formed by the server first sending a random nonce, and the client used the nonce to hash the password - this is allowed. But don't go reinventing the wheel...

Comment: Actually, the hashed password is only the password -for that site-.  If the hash includes a nonce/salt client-side, then an interceptor would be unable to reuse that password on another site.  Certainly -only- a client-side hash isn't acceptable, but it could potentially add a little obsfucation.

Comment: @Tchalvak: +1 for the first part of your comment. This is a thing developers often forget - by hashing we are protecting users' passwords on **OTHER** sites. Our site will be compromised anyway (if database contents are stolen).

Answer (score 3):

Its good to be paranoid when it comes to security, but in this case I dont think you have too much to worry about. The hash is strictly one way, so could never be converted back to a plaintext password.  The receiving party will simply make a check that the hash value sent matches the hash value they have stored.

The only concern then is ensuring that no-one can eavesdrop on the hashed password during transmission, so something like SSL should be used. If someone were to sniff the username + hashed password in transmission it could be reused by an attacker.

Comment: It would be better if the hashed password was salted with the sessionid or something. But of course, that could be sniffed too

Comment: @TiansHUo as long as u have access to the info exchanged u'll v. likely have access to the salt, I doubt there is any reason to it. The OP should just talk with them & find out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for that - when I sat down and thought it through, my thoughts mirrored this. I just wanted to make sure. I'd add you as the correct answer if I could do more than one, but I have to give it to Freddy Rios below because I think he's right to suggest I at least mention it to the developers at the other company, just in case they missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Details aside, this is an easy question to answer:

You can make all the effort in the world but if you are not using SSL, your authentication process can **EASILY** be exploited.